# Break out of infinite loop using a timer in Android

Tags: android, multithreading

In one of my projects, I require an infinite loop. To exit the loop the only condition is to set `flag = true` on some other thread.

```
flag = false;
While(true) {
   if (flag) break;
}
```

What would be the recommended way to break out of the loop using a timer? Say, if for the next 500ms the flag is not set to true, then force quit the loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `Handler.postDelayed()`. Note that I'm specifically using `Looper.getMainLooper()` as the thread for the `Handler` because I'm assuming you are doing the infinite loop on a background thread. If you are looping on the main thread that likely is not a good idea to begin with and you will have to update the `Handler` to use the `Looper` of a different thread.

```
new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper()).postDelayed(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        flag = true;
    }
}, 500);
```

Another option is to create a new `Thread`, sleep for the desired amount of time, and then set the flag accordingly.

```
new Thread(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        try {
            Thread.sleep(500);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            Log.e("Timeout Thread", "Interrupted", e);
        }

        flag = true;
    }
}).start();
```